# UseSqlServer is not defined in DbContextOptionBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

I am trying to configure entity framework 7 in my console application.

However , I noticed that "UseSqlServer" is not defined in DbContextOptionBuilder

Here is the code

```
public class LetsBreakITContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //country
            modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(c =>
           {
               c.HasKey(e => e.CountryId);
               c.Property(e => e.CountryId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
               c.Property(e => e.CountryId).IsRequired();
               c.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
           });
            //Book
            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>(l =>
            {
                l.HasKey(e => e.BookId);
                l.Property(e => e.BookId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                l.Property(e => e.CountryId).IsRequired();
                l.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
            });
        }
    }
```

I added EF 7 using Nuget "**install-package entityframework.commands -pre**"

I am using the sample code from Microsoft's EF 7 documentation
Not sure what I am missing here.

-Alan-

Comment: Did you install https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer/7.0.0-rc1-final ?

Comment: @ErikEJ, Yeah that is what I missed.  Can you answer this question, so that I can mark it as an aswer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to install the SqlServer provider: https://www.nuget.org/Packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/

Add this to your .csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />
```

Comment: No instructions, Link only answers are bad

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use MS SQL server, add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer nuget package to your project [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)

I'm using .NET Core 2.0. I used:
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.0.0

And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For EF 7 you also need the SQL "driver"

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.2" />
```